# How to get the firs row from each group-by object of pandas also for columns containing strings?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas data frame with the following columns: "user", "text1", "text2", and "time". I would like to group by user and for each user take the text corresponding to the largest time. I try to achieve this by the following code (using `first`):

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'user':['f','f','s'], 'text1':['111','222','333'], 'text2':[11,22,33], 'time':[1,2,3]}, columns=['user', 'text1', 'text2', 'time'])

print df    
print '----------------'

df = df.sort('time', ascending = False)

gr = df.groupby('user', as_index=False).first()
print gr
```

As a result I get the following:

```
  user text1  text2  time
0    f   111     11     1
1    f   222     22     2
2    s   333     33     3
----------------
  user  text2  time
0    f     22     2
1    s     33     3
```

As we can see it works for the `text2` contains integer numbers but not for the `text1` column that contains strings. Why does it happen and how one can resolve this problem?

Comment: What version pandas are you using, this worked fine for me on `0.14.1` with 64-bit python `3.3.5` and numpy `1.8.1`

Comment: I have: pandas==0.8.0, numpy==1.6.2, Python 2.7.3

Comment: I'd upgrade pandas and numpy and try again, it looks like a bug that has been previously fixed